# Add global menu / appmenu in xubuntu 11.10 64-bit (like mac/unity)?

Tags: 64-bit, xubuntu, appmenu, xfce, globalmenu

I've been looking a lot for this, but I just can't get a global menu to get working on Xubuntu 11.10 64-bit.
The best solution I've found is http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/10/how-to-enable-ubuntus-global-menu-in-xubuntu-11-10/ but it doesn't work: when I add the applet to the xfce panel, it seems to instantly crash.
When I run xfce4-panel in the console, the last 3 lines look pretty relevant:

> /usr/lib/xfce4-indicator-plugin/xfce4/panel-plugins/xfce4-appmenu-plugin: error while loading shared libraries: libxfce4panel-1.0.so.3: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
>
> xfce4-panel-Message: Plugin indicator-appmenu-29 has been automatically restarted after crash.
>
> /usr/lib/xfce4-indicator-plugin/xfce4/panel-plugins/xfce4-appmenu-plugin: error while loading shared libraries: libxfce4panel-1.0.so.3: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

This might indicate the plugin does not work on my 64bit OS, but I couldn't find a 64-bit alternative...

I would really appreciate if someone could help me a bit further with this. ANY way to get a global menu working will do! I got used to it on my hackintosh, and now I can't live without it. :)

PS: Although I stated [xubuntu] in the title, I actually run the default ubuntu, on top of which I installed xubuntu-desktop. I don't really use Unity anymore since it's too buggy without hardware acceleration.

Thank you in advance for the assistance, any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since i don't have an 64bit machine , i only published 32bit packages , please try to compile it from source code:

`http://opendesktop.org/content/show.php?content=146102`

On this page , i provided source code for downloading , you may need to run:

`sudo apt-get build-dep xfce4-indicator-plugin -y`

to get all development headers ahead of compilation

Comment: Thanks a lot, building it from source did help!! I got the appmenu working now, however, it seems to be unstable, it crashed after i started gedit:

    (xfce4-appmenu-plugin:10617): libxfce4panel-CRITICAL **: IA__xfce_panel_plugin_add_action_widget: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

    (xfce4-appmenu-plugin:10617): Indicator-Appmenu-CRITICAL **: Unable to claim the name com.canonical.AppMenu.Registrar

Comment: After a fresh restart the appmenu seems to be working like a charm (I still get the above-mentioned error, but anyway). Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: @Mr.Pixel , have you tried to log out and log in again ,  It's like some dbus interface wasn't exported yet. I installed gedit through apt-get , and it works smoothly.